# Trying to do a Podio API Call with Integromat getting back 403 forbidden - InvalidAccessTokenError

Tags: zapier, podio, make.com, integromat-apps

I face a problem with the Integromat Make an API call action to Podio. I want to make a Post request to add a user to a workspace which should be possible: https://developers.podio.com/doc/space-members/add-member-to-space-1066259.
However, when I try to do the Post request it gives me the following error back:

"InvalidAccessTokenError
Error: 403 Forbidden"

I tried to do a Get request for something else and this was possible. So, in my opinion the connection does work in general. What I am thinking is that the account version I am currently using is not good enough. I tried the API call with the free and the basic version, both did not work for me.

API call example: /space/XXXX/member?role=regular&message=hello&mails=MAIL@mail.com

I also tried the version with JSON code:

URL /space/XXXX/member

Body    {
"role": "regular",
"message": "Hello",
"mails": "MAIL@mail.com"
}

Any ideas from your side?

I am also open to Zapier if you know an easy way to do it with this software.

Best regards,
Matthias

Comment: Are you using HTTP module or Podio Make an API call?

Comment: I used Podio Make an API call.